# Making the input read integer conversions and be totalled into an equation

Tags: java

I have this code that takes a users input number and put it into an equation in the end. However, I keep getting an error/exception when compiling; 
"Error: variable convertToNumL might not have been initialized." I understand what the error is saying, however, I don't know how to debug this.

This is what I know, the try/catch block is somehow preventing the variable convertToNum (which is derived from the .readLine () method). Can anyone show me how to work around this?

Much appreciated.

Part of my code:

```
 if (realNumber2)
    {
      //Question 4: Height
      while (realNumber2 = true) {
        System.out.println ("3) Please enter the height of the triangle face.");


        try
        {
          stringTriangleHeight = myInput.readLine ();

          convertToNumH = Double.parseDouble (stringTriangleHeight);

          Integer.parseInt (stringTriangleHeight);

          System.out.println ("Your triangle height is " + stringTriangleHeight + " " + Units + ".");
          realNumber3 = true;

          break;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          System.out.println ("That was either a smart remark, a negative number or jibberish.");
          realNumber3 = true;
        }
      }
      while (realNumber3) {

      total1 = convertToNumL * convertToNumW;         //base area, length x width
      total2 = convertToNumL * convertToNumH / 2;     //triangle area using sidelength 'length', base x height / 2
      total3 = convertToNumW * convertToNumH / 2;     //triangle area using sidelength 'width  ,  base x height / 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the try catch block.  The problem is that `convertToNumH` is initialized in a while loop.  A while loop is not guaranteed to run (the condition might evaluate false the first time), so the value may never be initialized.

Either initialize it outside of the loop or use a Do-While loop instead.